# Button Click Callbacks

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a couple of user controls that are loaded at runtime that contain a bunch of buttons.  I register those button click events in my data class by getting a reference to the user control.  This is how I'm doing it now in my data class:

```
MainWindow.Instance.Menu1Instance.Button1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Button1_Click);
```

Problem is I'm going to have several user controls that need references and it seems kind of tedious.  I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this?

Comment: Do it from XAML, simply. You may also want to look into commanding in WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use data binding, see [ICommand is like a chocolate cake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mikehillberg/icommand-is-like-a-chocolate-cake).